# State column in a database table

Tags: database-design

I have a table that keep multiple version of each record, for example Id = 1 has two records, i am planning to add "STATE" column which will indicate the latest record from all versions. so latest record will have STATE = 1 and all older records will have STATE = 0.

```
Id NAME   STATE
1  Test1   0
1  Test1_1 1
2  TEST2   1
```

I have seen this design used in some other places also. if it's a recognized design what is it called? is it ok to implement in this way?

Comment: Google "versioning sql tables" & the more general "temporal data sql".

Comment: This is a bad design.  What will be your primary key?  I suggest something like `things_current (id PK, version FK)` and `things_history (id PK/FK, version PK, name)`.

Comment: this article explains what i m looking for, it is called "Slow Changing Dimension" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to track some or all changes made to the entities in a table, you want to be able to query current and past data (states) using the same query and you want foreign key references from other tables to work as they always do.

That is all possible, but the details are much too lengthy to put here. [Here](http://www.slideshare.net/TommCarr/bitemporal-rdbms-2014) is a slide show that goes into the details -- modeling and code. It could be a good part or perhaps all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a generally accepted name for it, but you don't need a name to be able to do it. If it feels good, code it.

I've done this on occassion. Usually I have some sort of version number or update date. In theory you could write queries to find the record that's the latest version, select max(version_stamp) or some such. In practice this is a pain, usually requring an inner query to find the right record and then an outer query to re-read that record. So this is one of the few cases where I tolerate redundant data, and add a "current" flag.

You probably want to make the primary key then be id+current, so you can find the current record without having to scan.

An alternative that I used once and I think I like but I'm still debating: Have one table with the full data and a unique id. Have another table with the "reference" id and then a FK to the full data. For example:

```
customer_data (customer_data_id*, date_stamp, name, address, credit_card_number, whatever)
customer (customer_number*, customer_data_id)
```

Then when customer_data is updated, we create a new record (with a new and unrelated customer_data_id), give it a date_stamp, and update customer to point to this new record.

Any time we want customer_data, we read it by joining on customer.

```
select name, address
from customer c
join customer_data d on d.customer_data_id=c.customer_data_id
where c.customer_number=@customer_number
```